# Can not get my form data passed to my php function

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, shortcode

Have a form on my Wordpress site that takes a zip code,  when submitted it will take you to a static page for that service area.  I am having trouble sending the data from my form to my php function.  I've tried playing with short code attributes and setting the form action to zip-finder.php.  Any help would be appreciated..

The form:

```
 /*<div class="zip"><form action="[zip_finder]" method='post'>Check           pricing and availability in your city or town: <input name='zip' size="12"     type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" /> <button id="zip"        type="submit">Get Started</button></form></div></p>
*/
I have added the line include('zip-finder.php'); to my theme    functions.php file.
```

the php file that process the form data:

```
//<?php
function zipfinder_function() {

$zip=$_POST['zip'];

//commented out some things I tried to get it to work
/*$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'zip' => 'something',
    'bar' => 'something else',
), $atts);*/

//switch ($atts['zip'])

   switch ('zip')
    {

            case "02052":
            header("Location: https://somewebsiteurl.com/");
            break;

            case "02056":
            header("Location: https://somewebsiteurl.com/");
            break;

            case "02090":
            header("Location: https://somewebsiteurl.com/");
            break;

            default;
            //header("Location: https://websiteurl.com/");
            break;
    }
 }
 add_shortcode('zip_finder', 'zipfinder_function');
//?>


I've tried using short code attributes:  [zip_finder zip="zip"]
```

Comment: `action="[zip_finder]"` is this your actual code? Action is supposed to be a URL

Comment: Yes this is the code.  action='[zip_finder]'

Comment: Yes this is the code.  action='[zip_finder]' and it does work.  In the the php file if I set $zip=02056;  it will go to the correct page for the zip code and service area.  I can not get the data from the form to work.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems you're switching a static value 'zip'. Try to switch the variable switch($zip).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Thank you Nick.  I made the change to switch ($zip) but still did not work.   After hitting submit it will bring to a new page: https://somewebsiteurl.com/[zip_finder]

Comment: As Joni commented, action is supposed to be an URL. You should point to the file which will process the posted data. That's why you end up at example.com/[zip_finder], you tell it to go there and post the value of zip. Point it to zip-finder.php